# Is it possible to plot realtime visualisations using SAS?

Tags: sas, real-time, visualization, data-visualization

I guess the question title says it all... I know it's possible to do such real-time plots in Matlab and Python for example but I'm not aware of any such real-time visualisations in SAS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what SAS tools are available to you and how real time you want it. It certainly possible with SAS Event Stream Processing Studio. Another way of doing it is to design a custom SAS stored process with JS front end and then frequently poll data from JS front end to update the graph/plot.

Regards,
Vasilij

Comment: Thanks - I wasn't aware of the Event Stream Processing Studio...!  I was thinking along the lines of 'hacking' a solution by plotting a graph of an in-memory hash table or something. Do you have any experience of performance/ability compared with (for example) MATLAB/D3.js?

Comment: Hi Bendy, D3 can live very comfortably on top of your existing SAS architecture given you have SAS Integration Technologies purchased. I don't have any experience of comparing one against the other as an experiment, but I am confident that MATLAB will be easier to set up for visualising smaller experiments for a single or small number of users. SAS will require a lot more coding to achieve the same effect, but it is a lot more scalable and will work a lot better with large (huge) amounts of data. Happy to discuss further in a chat or by email.